# MacOS Monterey (12.3) and Apache 2.53 https does not connect

Tags: apache, https, macos-monterey

On macOS Monterey (12.3.1) and Apache 2.53 (homebrew) I always receive (on Firefox)

`"Secure Connection Failed"`

`Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`

Other browsers will not connect as well.
No error message in apache logs and no record in access_log when trying https://localhost. While http: works fine

I recently upgraded from El Capitan (everything was fine there) and initially tried to use same Apache configs, then I googled the entire internet but found nothing that helps

Any idea how to handle it?

Comment: Install Wireshark and capture the TLS handshake.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I see no record with destination 127.0.0.1 on TCP port 443 on the capture

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what action was the last one but after computer restart localhost open on https with "connection not secure" notification, but it connects now! The certificate errors is not a problem for testing purpose. So, Apache restart is not enough sometimes!